# Excluding prefixes and suffixes from Faker("name")

Tags: factory-boy

I've noticed that `Faker("name")` sometimes return prefixes (e.g., Mr.) and suffixes (e.g., MD). Is there a good way to exclude prefixes and suffixes from the names generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could very well just concatenate `faker.first_name()` and `faker.last_name()`.